# CSS footer background color changes for no reason

Tags: css, background, footer

I have a page with two html files. I have exactly the same code for the footer in them. They use exactly the same CSS file but they look different and I still cannot find out why :

[image: HOW THE FOOTER SHOULD LOOK LIKE]

[image: HOW THE FOOTER LOOKS LIKE IN THE SECOND HTML FILE]

The code is here for the footer :

```
      <div class="container_12">
         <div class="grid_12"><footer>
            <div class="socials">
                <a href="#">facebook</a> | 
                <a href="#">twitter</a> | 
                <a href="#">google+</a>
            </div>
            <div class="copy">COSMOSET  &copy; 2013 | <a href="index.html">Privacy Policy</a> <!--{%FOOTER_LINK} -->
         </div></footer>

          </div>
    </div>
```

Also if you visit the page here: [HERE](http://aasiskos.webpages.auth.gr/COSMOSET/index-4.html)  you can see the text-box-areas do not have the same transparent white background. I assume this one is a server issue (plesk). Because when i open the file on my PC (saved on my PC) it looks perfect.

Comment: In the page that has a different background, do you have any in-file CSS code that may be interfering with the footer?

Comment: @Shaun No. I checked that. There are two css files that are being used in one of the files but no similar code in them. Also I updated the post with the second issue (i put the link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the second link from the left (of your navigator) you can see that you have the following DOM structure:

[image]

The problem is that, on the page your provided in your post, the footer is a sibling of the `<header>`, `<div class="clear">` and `<div class="bg1">` elements, as you can see it in the following screenshot:

[image]

Your problem will get solved if you move the `"container_12"` to be a sibling of the elements I mentioned above.

**LATER EDIT:**
To answer your second question, for the `#form textarea` CSS selector you've added an extra `.` after the `png` extenstion:

[image]

Comment: it worked. Now I would like to find a solution to no2 question

Comment: Uhh, which is the second question?

Comment: Check at the bottom of the 1st question. There is an issue with the css as well. That could be a server issue (plesk)

Comment: Great job. I can't believe it worked in my pc although I had this extra ".". This problem occured only in the online page. If you like you can check my second issue here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579229/js-gallery-copied-from-website-doesnt-work)